# Convert date to datetime (and give it default time) in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date, reactjs, datetime

I have an input in my React app that prompts user to select a date without time.

I am creating a scheduler that sends notification at specific time, say `7:00 PM`, the night before. So if user selects 5/17/2017, I want it to send reminder at `7:00 PM 5/16/2017`. I can do the math subtracting the day and hours, if they are both in `datetime` format. However, one data is in `date` format and another is in `datetime`.

The input I am using is simple input with `type="date"`. The output looks like `2017-05-25`. I tried adding `.setHours(15)` but it didn't work.

Is there a way to convert any given `date` to `datetime` and give them default time in Javascript? If I choose `2017-5-17` it will be converted to `Wed May 17 2017 19:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)`

Comment: what have you tried so far? code? also i suggest using [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) to play with date/times which is a pretty cool library for what you are trying to achive :)

Comment: Datetime is a DB object. You should convert this to a Date right at the start

Comment: @PaoloMangia I am having trouble replicating the `date` object.

I have been trying it on setState directly where the date is stored. If you understand react, `this.setState({date: e.target.value})` is the date (`e.target.value`). I tried extracting the day/month/year `e.target.value.getDay()`, `e.target.value.setHours(19)` with no luck.

Comment: @Iggy what's e.target.value? a string?

Comment: I agree with @PaoloMangia that you should look into momentjs. When you play around with the Javascript Date object, there are way too many factors you have to take into account to get the math working in your favor. Moment has done all the work for you.

Comment: @PaoloMangia—saying "use moment.js" is about as helpful as saying "use jQuery". If you have an answer involving a library, post it as an answer. Setting a Date to 7pm is as simple as `date.setHours(19,0,0,0)` (but that may not be suitable for react.js).

Comment: @PaoloMangia it is some sort of date object. What I pasted on my post is what it looks like on console.log on Google Chrome. The value is `2017-05-25`. No quotation marks, so I don't believe it is a string